# Android Notification not being shown

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I am trying to work with notifications. After problems, I tried to make the most-simple application with a button and when this button is clicked, a notification should show. However while the program does not crash or whatsoever, the notification is simply not being shown.

Any idea of what I am missing?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var notificationManager: NotificationManager
    private val channelId = "i.apps.notifications"
    private val description = "Test notification"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        createNotificationChannel()

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cooked_egg)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
        
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
                notify(3, builder.build())
            }

        }
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val descriptionText = description
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, 1.toString(), importance).apply {
                description = descriptionText
            }
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
}
```

I am creating a notification channel, an intent and then simply build the notification. However it is not being shown

Comment: Have you granted runtime permissions? https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission

Answer (score 0):

Add flags to your intent and change your pendindIntent like below then see if it works:

```
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        } else {
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        }
```